# Proving continuity of directional derivatives of $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ at $(0, 0)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

**Question:** Given $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x, y) =
\begin{cases}
x,  & \text{if $y=x^2$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$, show the directional derivatives of $f$ at $(0, 0)$ are continuous.

**Attempt:** 
Let $v=(a, b)$ be an arbitrary vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with magnitude $1$.

I have found by the limit definition of partial derivatives, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0, 0)=1$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0, 0)=0$.

Then, using the limit definition of directional derivative, the directional derivatives of $f$ at $(0, 0)$ in the direction of $v$ are $a$ and $0$ for vectors $hb=(ha)^2$ and $hb \ne (ha)^2$ respectively.

I am not sure how to show that these directional derivatives $a$ and $0$ are continuous. Do I need to prove this or is it obvious they're continuous since they're constants that don't depend on a variable?

Comment: Tip: to type "grad" in MathJax use ```\text{grad}``` ($\text{grad}$) or better still just use ```\nabla``` ($\nabla$)